# How can I get html code of the page in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I need to get html code of the website but I get only 403 error or 403 status_code

```
import urllib

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
html = data.decode('utf-8') # a `str`; this step can't be used if data is binary
print(html)
```

It will give this error

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

And I tried this too. (verify=False doesn't work too)

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://santehnika-online.ru/cart-link/b15caf63da6313698633f41747b9d9eb/', headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'})
print(res.text, res.status_code)
```

I got it. It is checking browser page, but it doesn't exist if I open this website in browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>Проверка браузера</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  </header>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper_message">
      <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-title">Проверяем браузер</div>
        <div>Сайт скоро откроется</div>
      </div>
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="captcha">
    <form id="challenge-form" class="challenge-form" action="/cart-link/b15caf63da6313698633f41747b9d9eb/?__cf_chl_f_tk=iRm3UPbqu59isE.16Z5X1Rx8TYQzALW_hvQcP9ji_Rc-1676103711-0-gaNycGzNCXs" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div id="cf-please-wait">
        <div id="spinner">
```

Help me please to get 200 status_code and good hrml code.

Comment: The site uses `cloudflare protection`, so you need a javascript interpreter. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419191/14900791)

Answer (score 0):

If getting a status code of 403, according to google:

> An HTTP 403 response code means that a client is forbidden from accessing a valid URL. The server understands the request, but it can't fulfill the request because of client-side issues.

So this means that the website is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get html websites (in my oppunion) is using Beautifulsoup library

simple

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Fetch the html file
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm')
html_doc = response.read()

# Parse the html file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# Format the parsed html file
strhtm = soup.prettify()

# Print the first few characters
print (strhtm[:225])
```

the best part for this library is usage like this
this part is extracting tag value

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm')
html_doc = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print (soup.title)
print(soup.title.string)
print(soup.a.string)
print(soup.b.string)
```

also about the error maybe IP blocking you can use proxy or other agents

but I think maybe website is using cookies you can track the website using console network in inspect to check if any suspicion cookies you get after going inside the website and add that cookie to your request and see the results

Answer (score 0):

The site is protected by `cloudflare` technology, which is currently one of the best. The `cloudflare` checks if the client can run `javascript` (this is the biggest difference between python `requests` and the browser).

Use these projects that are designed to pass through `cloudflare`'s protection:

- [cloudscrape](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper)
- [undetected selenium](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)